# Bitlocker unlock with Domain Login

Tags: bitlocker

Is it possible to have bitlocker (OS) unlock with domain login and then 'lock' and require bitlocker recovery key on failed password lock out, without 3rd party software?

A previous company had it setup this way, you were just presented with domain login and if you entered your credentials correctly, you went straight in to your deskop. 3 Failed password attempts and it kicked you back to bitlocker recovery and required the password.

My current company is requesting the same thing, I have added the Bitlocker Recovery tab to AD and set up the GPOs to backup the keys to AD.

I have tried using -sid with Domain\User but bitlocker is still hitting the preboot environment.

Would I need to have two separate drives? Encrypt data and leave System alone?

Comment: See [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-machine-account-lockout-threshold).

Comment: As far as I know plain Bitlocker using TPM+PIN you always have to enter the TPM PIN and not the user credentials in the preboot environment. I assume that there are third party products that allow to authenticate using domain account in pre-boot environment.